# Invalidate CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've defined the following view:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="PatientsView" Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=Patients}"/>
```

Where Patient is the following property:

```
public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients
{
    get
    {
        return from patient in Database.Patients
               orderby patient.Lastname
               select patient;
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my code, I change the Patients database, and I want to have the controls that display this data (using the "PatientsView") to be automatically notified. What's a proper way to do this?
Can the CollectionViewSource be invalidated or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bit more complex than it seems. Notifying your client application about changes in database is a non-trivial task. But your life is easier if the database is changed only from your application - this makes you able to put "refreshing logic" whenever you change the database.

Your "Patients" property seems to be present in one class (maybe a little more than one? :) ). And you probably bind some ListBox to the CollectionViewSource. So instead of calling Refresh on the CollectionViewSource you can make WPF re-call the getter. For this the class that has Patients property has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

The code would look like this:

```
public class TheClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public IEnumerable<Patient> Patients
  {
    get
    {
            return from patient in Database.Patients
                   orderby patient.Lastname
                   select patient;
    }
  }

#region INotifyPropertyChanged members
// Generated code here
#endregion

public void PatientsUpdated()
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, "Patients");
}
}
```

Now, call PatientsUpdated() on an instance of TheClass to trigger update of the binding.

P.S. Having said all that it just feels like a bad design somehow.

Comment: All my changes are done locally in the application, so I can add the refresh logic. However, calling Refresh() has no effect!

Comment: I've modified my post with some more thoughts.

Comment: This is it. Still don't know why Refresh() does not work, but this works fine! Thanks

Comment: _instead of calling Refresh on the CollectionViewSource you can make WPF re-call the getter_. Why do you think that updating the binding is better than the simple call of 'CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh()'?

Answer (score 7):

How to invalidate a CollectionViewSource in code behind:

```
CollectionViewSource patientsView = FindResource("PatientsView") as CollectionViewSource;
patientsView.View.Refresh();
```

Comment: I've tried this code. Nothing happens when refresh is called! I set a breakpoint on my Patients property: it is not called when Refresh() is called..

Answer (score 0):

`Table<T>` does not support `IListChanged` events, you will have to do this yourself (I had to do the same earlier today).